# Banach spaces and Normed linear spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Here's a theorem:
A normed linear space X is a Banach space iff every absolutely convergent series in X is convergent.  How is this possible? I need the proof.

Comment: Show that that condition is equivalent to "every Cauchy sequence is convergent". Construct a Cauchy sequence from the terms of an absolutely convergent series, and extract an absolutely convergent series from (a subsequence of) a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

$\implies$: Suppose $\sum_n a_n$ is absolutely convergent, i.e. $\sum_n\|a_n\|$ is convergent in $\Bbb R$. Then use triangle inequality to show that the corresponding sequence
$$s_n:=\sum_{k\le n}a_k$$
is Cauchy.

$\Longleftarrow$: If $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then select a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $\ \|a_{n_{k+1}}-a_{n_k}\|< \displaystyle\frac1{2^n}$, and define $b_k:=a_{n_{k+1}}-a_{n_k}$ with $b_0:=a_{n_0}$. Then $\sum_n b_n$ is an absolute convergent series, so it converges, and then by the Cauchy property conclude that its limit point must be the limit of $(a_n)$.

Comment: Ok. Pls check this theorem out, is there anything like: Let X be a normed linear space. Then the normed conjugate X' of X is complement.     Is that suppose to be complement or complete?